# How to edit data which is in json format in a url using php?

Tags: php, json

This is my url `http://localhost:4000/users`.

The json data looks like this:

```
"users": [
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Admin",
  "email": "admin@gmail.com",
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "e19d5cd5af0378da05f63f891c7467af",
  "wallet_address": "4p7tg5cb2yulvmz3sjfeanoi0r8wkdx4h69q",
  "balance": "1000"
},
]
```

I want to change the balance. How do I do it? I tried this code:

```
$url = "http://localhost:4000/users";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$decodedData = json_decode($data);

for ($i=0; $i<count($decodedData); $i++) {
    if ($decodedData[$i]->username == $_SESSION['username']) {
        
        $decodedData[$i]->balance = $decodedData[$i]->balance - $amount;
    
        $data4 = array("name"=>$decodedData[$i]->name, "email"=>$decodedData[$i]->email, 
        "username"=>$decodedData[$i]->username, "password"=>$decodedData[$i]->password, 
        "wallet_address"=>$decodedData[$i]->wallet_address, "balance"=>$decodedData[$i]->balance);

        $options4 = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method'  => 'PUT',
                'content' => http_build_query($data4)
            )
        );

        $context4  = stream_context_create($options4);
        $result_users = file_get_contents($url, false, $context4);
    }
}
```

But I get this warning

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost:4000/users): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in ....
```

I removed the last 2 lines from my code and now the warning is not showing. But still the value of balance is not changing.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Sounds like the URL either isn't correct or isn't accessible from where PHP is running. Are you running this code on the same machine where the URL is hosted? Is the webserver which listens on that URL definitely up and running?

Comment: The url is correct. And I am running the code on the same machine where the url is hosted. I have used POST method successfully like this `'method'  => 'POST',`

Comment: I removed the last 2 lines from my code and now the warning is not showing. But still the value of balance is not changing.

Comment: Do you, by chance, have error reporting (error_reporting) set off?

Comment: `error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT` and `display_errors=On` in my php.ini

Comment: OK. With the above JSON(?) data I received an error when testing regarding the `count` method but after some playing around ( with source data initially to make it json ) I have this more or less working except for the PUT command which is yielding `405-Method Not Allowed`

Comment: Earlier I was using POST command to post data successfully. But now I have to change the value of balance. So I replaced POST with PUT.

Comment: The problem for me is not the editing of the source data but the PUT method...